# Calendar Script - Mapping ID and Date in the Date Columns

Tags: php, mysql, date

I am creating a Calendar for a guest house. It simply tells the dates Booked or Available.
Green color for Available and Red for Booked.

All is working good but i want to make it editable means for Available date there should be a link "Book It" and for Booked date there should be a link "Unbooked".

My script is actually fetching ID and Date from table and store in an array (There are only these two columns in that table BTW). Then using **in_arrary** function it simply makes red for all those dates which found in table and leave all other dates green.

I am facing difficulties to map or populate ID and Date values can anyone help me.

In a nutshell i want ID and Date values print on the date columns so i can make links. For Booked dates, **ID** should be passed to next page so i can delete it and make it available again. And for available dates, **Date** should be passed on next page so i add that date in table and make it Booked.

Here is my complete script:

```
<?php

error_reporting(0);
include("config.php");

/// get current month and year and store them in $cMonth and $cYear variables
(intval($_REQUEST["month"])>0) ? $cMonth = $_REQUEST["month"] : $cMonth = date("n");
(intval($_REQUEST["year"])>0) ? $cYear = $_REQUEST["year"] : $cYear = date("Y");

if ($cMonth<10) $cMonth = '0'.$cMonth;

// generate an array with all unavailable dates
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." WHERE `date` LIKE '".$cYear."-".$cMonth."-%'";
$sql_result = mysql_query ($sql, $connection ) or die ('request "Could not execute SQL query" '.$sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result)) {
$unavailable[] = $row["date"];
}


// calculate next and prev month and year used for next / prev month navigation links and store them in respective variables
$prev_year = $cYear;
$next_year = $cYear;
$prev_month = intval($cMonth)-1;
$next_month = intval($cMonth)+1;

// if current month is Decembe or January month navigation links have to be updated to point to next / prev years
if ($cMonth == 12 ) {
$next_month = 1;
$next_year = $cYear + 1;
} elseif ($cMonth == 1 ) {
$prev_month = 12;
$prev_year = $cYear - 1;
}
?>
<table style="width:100%; text-align: center;">
<tr>
    <td class="mNav"><a href="javascript:LoadMonth('<?php echo $prev_month; ?>', '<?php echo $prev_year; ?>')">&lt;&lt;&nbsp;Prev</a></td>
    <td colspan="5" class="cMonth"><?php echo date("F, Y",strtotime($cYear."-".$cMonth."-01")); ?></td>
    <td class="mNav"><a href="javascript:LoadMonth('<?php echo $next_month; ?>', '<?php echo $next_year; ?>')">Next&nbsp;&gt;&gt;</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="width:16%;" class="wDays">M</td>
    <td style="width:14%;" class="wDays">T</td>
    <td style="width:14%;" class="wDays">W</td>
    <td style="width:14%;" class="wDays">T</td>
    <td style="width:14%;" class="wDays">F</td>
    <td style="width:14%;" class="wDays">S</td>
    <td style="width:14%;" class="wDays">S</td>
</tr>
<?php 
$first_day_timestamp = mktime(0,0,0,$cMonth,1,$cYear); // time stamp for first day of the month used to calculate 
$maxday = date("t",$first_day_timestamp); // number of days in current month
$thismonth = getdate($first_day_timestamp); // find out which day of the week the first date of the month is
$startday = $thismonth['wday'] ; // 0 is for Sunday and as we want week to start on Mon we subtract 1
if (!$thismonth['wday']) $startday = 7;


for ($i=1; $i<($maxday+$startday); $i++) {


if (($i % 7) == 1 ) echo "<tr>";

if ($i < $startday) { echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>"; continue; };

$current_day = $i - $startday + 1;

(in_array($cYear."-".$cMonth."-".$current_day,$unavailable)) ? $css='booked' : $css='available'; // set css class name based on date availability


if ($css == 'booked') { 
echo "<td class='".$css."'>". $current_day . "<br/>" . "Booked" . "</td>";
}
elseif ($css == 'available') {
echo "<td class='".$css."'>". $current_day . "<br/>" . "Available" . "</td>";
}

if (($i % 7) == 0 ) echo "</tr>";

}
?> 
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the `id` to the `$unavailable` array, so that you can add it to the link later. The easiest would be to use it as the array key -

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result)) {
   $unavailable[$row["id"]] = $row["date"];
}
```

Then when you are building each day cell, use `array_search()` to get the array key of the booked date, and use the date for the available date -

```
if ($css == 'booked') { 
    echo "<td class='".$css."'>". $current_day . "<br/>" . "Booked" . "<br/>" . "<a href='scheduler_page.php?id=".array_search($cYear."-".$cMonth."-".$current_day,$unavailable)."'>Unbook</a>" . "</td>";
}
elseif ($css == 'available') {
    echo "<td class='".$css."'>". $current_day . "<br/>" . "Available" . "<br/>" . "<a href='scheduler_page.php?date=".$cYear."-".$cMonth."-".$current_day."'>Book it</a>" . "</td>";
}
```

Then on your next page, my example uses `scheduler_page.php`, you can `$_GET` to determine weither to unschedule or book -

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
   // unbook the date
}
elseif(isset($_GET['date'])){
   // schedule the date
}
```

Comment: Hi Sean, Thanks your solution resolved most of the problem and now available dates are showing correct Book It link with correct date in parameter to be used later. But problem is on those dates which are already in table means booked dates. After applying your solution now there is only one date column showing in red and link Unbook but without id in parameter. I think there should be a little tweak missing to make it perfect can you please help.

Comment: By the way i have 3 ids in table right now, id=1 date=2014-02-21, id=2 date=2014-02-15, id=3 date=2014-02-16. It looks like its not getting id value

Comment: When i am printing the array $unavailable[$row["id"]] = $row["date"]; it's showing only last date 2014-02-16 which has id 3.

Comment: Resolved.

Thanks Sean you've done it, really useful solution.
Your code was perfect only amendment which i done is instead of * i used id, date in my query and it worked.

Thanks